# Problem with performing a groupby count using an annotated field

Tags: python, sql-server, django

#### Context

I have a table/model called **Article**.

Within this model, I have several fields such as expiry date, visibility, and status. These fields determine if the Article should be displayed or not. Essentially, the desired logic is like so:

```
display = True
if status == 'Private'; display = False
if visibility == False; display = False
...
```

For the sake of simplicity, in this post, I'm just going to be using **one** field: `status`. The `status` field is a `CharField` with choices being `'Private'` or `'Public'`.

In order to work out the display logic, I use annotation. This is relatively simple:

```py
all_articles = Article.objects.annotate(
    display=Case(When(status='Private', then=Value(False)), default=Value(True), output_field=models.BooleanField())
)

displayed_articles = all_articles.filter(display=True)
notdisplayed_articles = all_articles.filter(display=False)
```

#### Goal

With this setup, I would like to use Django ORM to perform a count with group by to determine how many articles are being displayed, and how many are not.

The outcome would like like this in SQL tabular format:

| display | count |
| --- | --- |
| True | 500 |
| False | 2000 |

#### Problem

This is the natural way to achieve my goal:

```py
queryset = Article.objects.annotate(
    display=Case(
        When(status='Private', then=Value(False)), default=Value(True), output_field=models.BooleanField()
    )
).values('display').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by()

print(queryset)
```

#### Expectation

I'm expecting something like this:

```py
<QuerySet [{'display': True, 'count': 500}, {'display': False, 'count': 2000}]>
```

#### Error

However, I'm getting this:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'blog_article.status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (8120) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Why is this happening and how can I get around this?

#### Investigation into the SQL Query

I have looked into the generated SQL Query by:

```py
print(queryset.query)
```

```sql
SELECT CASE
        WHEN [blog_article].[status] = Private THEN False
        ELSE True
    END AS [display],
    COUNT_BIG([blog_article].[id]) AS [count]
FROM [blog_article]
GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN [blog_article].[status] = Private THEN False
        ELSE True
    END
```

The general structure of the query looks OK, I only needed to make some small changes to it. The below query **was executed successfully against the database.**

```sql
SELECT CASE
        WHEN [faq_faq].[status_type] = 'Private' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS [display],
    COUNT_BIG([faq_faq].[id]) AS [count]
FROM [faq_faq]
GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN [faq_faq].[status_type] = 'Private' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
```

I have also tested running this query using `pyodbc`, and it was executed successfully.

Comment: `The below query was executed successfully against the database.` I don't think so. There are several error in that query

Comment: @Squirrel Apologies, I made some small typos with the SQL Query and have fixed it by changing double quotes `"` to single quote`'` and changing True to 1